# pop up window immediately closing as soon after the window open after clicking the button

Tags: next.js, next-auth, react-new-window

hey folks can anyone check my code because when I click on the login button new window opens up and immediately it closes I don't what the problem is I'm using

```
import NewWindow from 'react-new-window';
```

`const [newWindow, setnewWindow] = useState(false);`

```
<Button onClick={() => setnewWindow(true)}>Login</Button>
{ newWindow && !session ? ( <NewWindow url='../components/signIn' onUnload={() => setnewWindow(false)} />) : null }
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const SignInPage = () => {
    const { data: session, status="loading" } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!status && !session ) void signIn('discord');
        if(!status && session) window.close();
    }, [ session, status ])
    return null;
}

export default SignInPage;
```

Comment: Is the code execution getting inside this `if` block `if(!status && session) window.close();`?

Comment: yes its happening inside if block

Comment: So that's why it's closing, you're calling `window.close()`.

Comment: so what changes should i make to the code so that new window closes after the authentication is complete